# Push ObjectId to nested array in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

(Basic library CRUD application)

I am trying to create a document containing some global data about a given book, and then within a User document, add the ObjectId of the newly-created book to an array containing all books belonging to that user.

I have three data models in my application:

```js
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    books: [BookInstanceSchema],
    shelves: [String]
});

var bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: String,
    pageCount: Number,
    ISBN: String,
    googleID: String,
    thumbnail: String,
    publisher: String,
    published: String,
});

var BookInstanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    bookId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Book'
    },
    userReview: String,
    userRating: {
        type: Number,
        get: v => Math.round(v),
        set: v => Math.round(v),
        min: 0,
        max: 4,
        default: 0
    },
    shelf: String
});
```

The User model contains a nested array of BookInstances, which contain user-specific data such as ratings or reviews for a given book. A bookInstance in turn contains a reference to the global data for a book, to avoid duplicating data that isn't specific to any user.

What I'm trying to do is first save the global data for a book (thus generating an _id), and when done, save a bookInstance containing that _id in a given user's array of books:

```js
router.post('/save/:id', function(req, res) {

    var url = encodeurl('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/' + req.params.id);

    request(url, function(err, response, data) {

        parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

        var newBook = {
            title: parsedData.volumeInfo.title,
            author: parsedData.volumeInfo.authors[0],
            description: parsedData.volumeInfo.description,
            pageCount: parsedData.volumeInfo.pageCount,
            ISBN: parsedData.volumeInfo.description,
            googleID: parsedData.id,
            publisher: parsedData.volumeInfo.publisher,
            published: parsedData.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
            thumbnail: parsedData.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail
        };

        Book.create(newBook, function(err, newBook) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else {

                console.log(newBook._id);
                console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(newbook._id));

                User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.session.id, {
                    $push: {
                        "books": {
                            bookId: newBook._id,
                            userRating: 0,
                            userReview: ''
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    upsert: true
                },
                function(err, data){
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        res.redirect('/');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```
I'm getting the error: 

  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "hjhHy8TcIQ6lOjHRJZ12LPU1B0AySrS0" at path "_id" for model "User"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"hjhHy8TcIQ6lOjHRJZ12LPU1B0AySrS0"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'hjhHy8TcIQ6lOjHRJZ12LPU1B0AySrS0',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
```

Every time, the value in the error (in this case, jhHy8T...) is different than the newBook._id I'm attempting to push into the array:

```
console.log(newBook._id); // 5a120272d4201d4399e465f5
console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(newBook._id)); // true
```

It seems to me something is wrong with my User update statement:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.session.id, {
$push: {
    "books": {
        bookId: newBook._id,
        userRating: 0,
        userReview: ''
    }
}...
```

Any help or suggestions on how to better organize my data are appreciated. Thanks!